# How to fix "firestore: quota exceeded error while uploading rules"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am getting an error when deploying rules using the deploy command in CI

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:rules --non-interactive
```

Output:

```
i  deploying firestore
i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
✔  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: uploading rules firestore.rules...
i  firestore: quota exceeded error while uploading rules
? You have 2501 rules, do you want to delete the oldest 10 to free up space? (y/N)
```

I can fix the problem temporarily by deleting the last 10 manually, but will hit the limit again soon.  Is there an easier way to purge the rules history using cli?

Comment: If you specify `--yes` in the call to `firebase deploy`, it will auto-confirm the deletion of the oldest 10 rule deploys.

Comment: I tried it with firebase-tools 6.9.2.  I get `error: unknown option '--yes'`

Comment: added `-f` to the command and this seems to auto-confirm.  thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Ah, was that it. I searched in the help, but couldn't find the correct parameter. Good to hear that you found it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this is not working with version 7.0.0 :(

Comment: If there was a regression in behavior that might be a bug. Can you show exactly what call worked before and doesn't work anymore now?

Comment: updated the answer below with the versions versions.  the one that has stopped worked before is `firebase deploy --only firestore:rules --non-interactive -f`

Comment: Good to hear that you found a workaround. Unless the removal of the `-f` was mentioned in the release notes (where I don't immediately see it), this might be an unintended regression. I'd recommend opening a bug on the CLI repo: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues

Answer (score 4):

using `-f` option the rules are deployed without asking to delete using firebase-tools 6.9.2

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:rules --non-interactive -f
```

#### UPDATE

this is not working anymore with firebase-tools 7.0.0

#### Workaround found

```
echo y | firebase deploy  --only firestore:rules
```

Answer (score 2):

The helpful firebase support also sent us the below advice to deal with this issue.

> It looks like you are hitting the rule set deployment limit. As of the
>   moment, I can only suggest the manual deletion of old rules.
>
> If you're deploying your app and you have no changes in your Firestore
>   security rules, I recommend doing a partial deployment to avoid
>   hitting the rule set limit.
>
> You can also use the Firebase Rules API to list or delete the rule
>   sets of your project.
>
> There is already an existing Feature Request on how to handle this
>   issue. However, I cannot provide an exact timeline for our releases. I
>   will suggest visiting our blog page or release notes for the latest
>   news.