# Can't deploy anymore into Firebase - "too many rules"

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-cli

Our project was working great, till today at some point after multiple deployments using terminal, i couldn't deploy any more :

```
  storage: quota exceeded error while uploading rules
 HTTP Error: 429, Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).
```

You have 2501 rules, do you want to delete the oldest 10 to free up space? (y/
N)

I am on a **premium plan - pay as you use.** on Firebase. I don't think  i crossed any limit ( single developer).

Why do  i have so many rules ? i am not sure i have added any rules other than the basic read/write rules rules.

Do i add rules every deployment somehow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you've been working on this project for quite some time, and are adding a new rules version at every `firebase deploy`. The limit of 2500 rule set versions is not tied to any paid/free plan, but is a hard limit for all Firebase projects.

You'll want to check your `firebase.json` file for a `rules` node in that case. If that exists, every call to `firebase deploy` will also redeploy your security rules. See the [reference docs for the CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deployment), and the [documentation on deploying rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy).

If you don't want to redeploy the rules every time you call `firebase deploy`, consider only deploying the modules you modified for example `firebase deploy --only hosting` or `firebase deploy --only functions`.

Comment: thanks, i am not sure i understand. inside that json i have   "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules" } , and the same for "firebase" node. What do i have to do to clear those 2500 (!) rules ?

Comment: The message says "You have 2501 rules, do you want to delete the oldest 10 to free up space? (y/ N)", so you can answer `y` to delete the oldest 10 rule sets. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050175/) you can also use the rules API to delete older rulesets.

Comment: thanks Frank for helping here. I wanted to delete them all to not having this problem again. Something here is strange, rules should exist once. Why would someone keep duplicating the rules every deployment ? sounds like a bad design unless i am really clueless.